# Getting optional value crash on sign up

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to do sign up, I am getting the correct response. But after get success .I am getting crash as optional value.

Here is my full code :

```
   var post:NSString = "name=\(Username)&email=\(Email)&phone=\(phonenumb)&password=\(Password)&address=\(address)"

    NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://userregistration.php")!
   // let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://userregistration.php")!

    let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    let reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    do {
        let urlData = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);


                do {
                    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                    let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                    //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                    NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog("Sign Up SUCCESS");
                        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        var error_msg:NSString

                        if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                            error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                        } else {
                            error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                        }
                        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView.title = "Sign Up Failed!"
                        alertView.message = error_msg as String
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView.show()

                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }



            } else {
                let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Sign Up Failed!"
                alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And i am getting crash in this line :

```
 let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger
```

The error is option value crash.I dont know how to handle this error.Does any expert please give me some idea or some solution to rectify this crash

Comment: Because `jsonData.valueForKey("success")` is nill. Check your response.

Comment: That means.What should i need to chnage

Comment: `Response ==> {"status":1,"message":"Registration successfull.","CustomerId":2}
2016-08-09 12:39:02.228 M-Commerce[1454:71029] error is next line: 140725375544912
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
`

Comment: This is what i got !!

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I am getting error : ` Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'NSInteger' (aka 'Int')`

Comment: First try to get that object without any casting after that once you got object successfully then cast it as `Int`

Answer (score 0):

Always use safe unwrapping, and don't directly try to unwrap/cast values that can be nil.

Correct way is-

```
if let successVal = jsonData["success"] as? NSInteger {
   //Do something with successVal. 
}
```

Though not directly related to your problem, wanted to point your using deprecated NSURLConnection API, instead use NSURLSession based APIs for networking.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response you will not receive any `success` but only `status` are you sure you haven't to check for that value?

Also I do suggest you to move your code to something like:

```
guard let success = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as? Int else {
asset('Check your response, is missing success key')
return
}
```